# Allow feedback to the SO team about companies, when they themselves may not be able to

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

I've been seeing an advert for jobs for Manor Racing pop up for a month or two:

[image]

For those that don't follow F1, this team [has sadly recently folded](http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/formula1/38772098) after a buyer was not found.

I was hoping there would be something on the job advert itself or on [the company page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/manor-racing) where I could provide feedback to the SO team to potentially follow up with the employer so the advert can be removed from circulation (as I think it's unlikely that these positions still exist), but I was unable to find a way to do so.  Normal adverts have the thumbs up/down icons - but there doesn't seem to be anything at all for job ads.

---

Cody Gray, in a comment below, mentioned:

> On the job listing itself, you can "flag a problem" (in the right-hand side bar), but I don't think there is any such option for the entire company. There probably should be.

I've now done this in this particular instance.  However, in the larger view - a company that's gone into administration is probably not in a hurry to keep things such as their company page on a 3rd party website updated.  It would be good to be able to provide feedback to the SO team at the company level via their page.

Comment: On the job listing itself, you can "flag a problem" (in the right-hand side bar), but I don't think there is any such option for the entire company. There probably should be.

Comment: @CodyGray Ah, I have to admit I didn't actually click on any single job in the list

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks - flagged one of the jobs and have turned this into a broader feature request about feedback on companies in general

Comment: Agree that being able to flag a company would be useful. This isn't the next thing on our list but will update this post if we start exploring this.

Comment: I suppose they should have posted a job listing for team owner...

Comment: It's not strictly over yet for them. Company could be bought at any time in the next days. And I hope so, I'm a F1 fan and they were been doing great in the last years. Good luck to them.

Comment: @wes indeed - hence saying the positions are unlikely to still be open :)  I too would rather see a return to the days of more teams - always more fun!

Comment: This isn't really SO's problem I think. Supposedly the company has paid for the advert in advance. So even if that company is now bankrupt, they might have paid for the advert to show for a certain time. If they want to take it down, then it's that company's problem.

Comment: @Lundin Fair point.  To slightly counter it - SO talks about the aim of making developers lives easier, so if we're able to provide info that an advert probably shouldn't be showing, and maybe wasting devs time, it at least gives another feedback route to let them judge if an advert/company should stay up or not

Comment: @JamesThorpe Making devs lives easier is just marketing BS. An advert about a job at a company that is bankrupt is as irrelevant to me as a job located half-ways across the continent. These job adverts have very little to do with making devs lives easier, and very much to do with SO providing mass spam opportunities in return for cash.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In cases like this, flagging the listing and indicating the company is no longer trading (just as you did) should suffice. I've spoken to their account manager internally and will take down the listings and unpublish their company page.

Comment: Do you not see the merit in adding a similar "flag" link to the company page, for issues with that page or those that affect the entire company? I realize this isn't a high-priority item, but it might be something to consider.

Comment: Great question, I'll raise it with my team however broadly speaking it's quite rare for things like this to happen. When in doubt, feel free to either report any associated jobs, or if it's in regards to a company page where there's no report function, send an email to talent@stackoverflow.com.